# Magento related products get category

Tags: php, category, html, related-products, product-relations

I want to edit my `/catalog/product/list/related.phtml` file.

I want to define all related products based on their main category. So for example that all mices are displayed in their category "**Mices**" and all keyboards are also display in their category "**Keyboards**".

Therefore I need to edit the code below into the correct one. So I need to get the main category of the related products and display all content based on these categories. I already tried something in the code below, but that does not work.

How can I achieve that? Anyone who knows how to achieve this?

**Magento version 1.9.2.4**

For example what I want:

```
<div>
<h1>Mices</h1>
<ul>
<li>product 1</li>
<li>product 2</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div>
<h1>Keyboards</h1>
<ul>
<li>product 1</li>
<li>product 2</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I get the category name by using the following code. But now I need to edit the `foreach`, so that it display all items inside a specific category.

```
<?php $categoryIds = $_item->getCategoryIds(); 
                    if(count($categoryIds) ){
                        $firstCategoryId = $categoryIds[0];
                        $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($firstCategoryId);
                    echo $_category->getName();
            }?>
```

Current `related.phtml`:

```
<?php if($this->getItems()->getSize()): ?>
<div class="block block-related">
    <div class="block-title">
        <h3><?php echo $this->__('Related Products') ?></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <p class="block-subtitle"><?php echo $this->__('Check items to add to the cart or') ?>&nbsp;<a href="#" onclick="selectAllRelated(this); return false;"><?php echo $this->__('select all') ?></a></p>
        <ol class="mini-products-list" id="block-related">
        <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>

        <?php $categoryIds = $_item->getCategoryIds(); 
                    if(count($categoryIds) ){
                        $firstCategoryId = $categoryIds[0];
                        $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($firstCategoryId);
                    echo $_category->getName();
            }?>
        <?php foreach($_category->getName() as $_categoryitems): ?>    
            <h1><?php echo $_category->getName();?></h1> 
            <li class="item">
                <?php if(!$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()): ?>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox related-checkbox" id="related-checkbox<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" name="related_products[]" value="<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" />
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="product">
                    <a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'thumbnail')->resize(100) ?>" width="100" height="100" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>" /></a>
                    <div class="product-details">
                        <p class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?></a></p>
                        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true, '-related') ?>
                        <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                            <a title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?>" href="<?php echo $this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_item) ?>" class="link-wishlist"> </a>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach ?>    

        <?php endforeach ?>
        </ol>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('block-related', 'none-recursive')</script>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    $$('.related-checkbox').each(function(elem){
        Event.observe(elem, 'click', addRelatedToProduct)
    });
    var relatedProductsCheckFlag = false;
    function selectAllRelated(txt){
        if (relatedProductsCheckFlag == false) {
            $$('.related-checkbox').each(function(elem){
                elem.checked = true;
            });
            relatedProductsCheckFlag = true;
            txt.innerHTML="<?php echo $this->__('unselect all') ?>";
        } else {
            $$('.related-checkbox').each(function(elem){
                elem.checked = false;
            });
            relatedProductsCheckFlag = false;
            txt.innerHTML="<?php echo $this->__('select all') ?>";
        }
        addRelatedToProduct();
    }
    function addRelatedToProduct(){
        var checkboxes = $$('.related-checkbox');
        var values = [];
        for(var i=0;i<checkboxes.length;i++){
            if(checkboxes[i].checked) values.push(checkboxes[i].value);
        }
        if($('related-products-field')){
            $('related-products-field').value = values.join(',');
        }
    }
    //]]>
    </script>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Did you ever get this implemented? We would also like to configure the default related items block to show only items from the same assigned category. RP

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/145254)